# JKQtPlotter не работают примеры

Tags: c++, qt, lib

Пытаюсь скомпилировать какой нибудь пример этой библиотеки, но выходят ошибки
https://marketplace.qt.io/products/jkqtplotter 
2021-05-21T21:46:40 Модель кода Clang: Ошибка: Не удалось запустить программу clangbackend «C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\clangbackend.exe» (истекло время: 10000 мс).

:-1: ошибка: cannot find -ljkqtplotterlib_debug

Хотя в примерах, уже должно всё работать. В чем проблема? Посоветуйте, пожалуйтса как исправить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что QtCreator не создавал .exe файл, после того как все примеры из этого файла были скомпилированы, нужный мне пример не билдился по дефолту. Также я обновила QtCreator и в сумме это решило проблему